# Is it safe to promisify requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to promisify `requestAnimationFrame`?

For example:

```js
const raf = (cb) => new Promise((resolve) => 
    requestAnimationFrame(() => (cb(), resolve())))

const gameLoop = async () => { while(1) await raf(draw) }
```

Comment: @trincot "Just note that these two microtasks (the one in which resolve runs, and the one in which draw runs) belong to the same task (core EcmaScript). But since I was downvoted, I will remove my answer.." It wasn't my downvote. If you are saying that `resolve` and `draw` will run in the same microtask, I am willing to engage with that.

Comment: Safe in regards to what?

Comment: Will `requestAnimationFrame` still work expectedly, with `draw` being run at the "appropriate" time, and what are the downsides to this approach?

Comment: The obvious downside with the code in the question is that when `draw` throws an exception, you do not get a promise rejection, it just hangs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it safe to promisify `requestAnimationFrame`?

Yes:

```
function raf() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
    });
}
```

> For example:
>
> ```
> const raf = (cb) => new Promise((resolve) => 
>     requestAnimationFrame(() => (cb(), resolve())))
> ```

No, *that* one is not safe. A promise-returning function should never take an asynchronous callback. The drawing stuff stuff should be done inside the promise chain, your code does it before even resolving the promise, and lacks any proper error handling. If `cb()` throws an exception, you're screwed.

The simple approach without a callback works just fine, as `requestAnimationFrame` schedules a macrotask, and any microtasks scheduled by the `resolve` callback are run before the frame is actually painted. Your code should be

```
async function gameLoop() {
    while (true) {
        await raf();
        draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: My concern was that the microtask that `draw` is invoked within (equivalent to a `.then`) would somehow break the timing of `requestAnimationFrame`. So microtasks block rendering?

Comment: Yes, when the `requestAnimationFrame` callback is called, it waits for all queued microtasks to finish before continuing to the painting step.

Comment: This is great but your first example could have been abstracted better like `raf().then(cb)`.

Comment: @Redu If you mean the code after "*For example:*", that's a quote from the OP, and in the paragraph after it I explain why it's bad

Comment: @Bergi Yes that part is "bad" as you explain and i upvoted. At the same time i recall you as one of the few promise mindset oriented people (even had written a library if i remember correctly). With all due respect, i would expect you to show something apart from imperative `async await` abstraction but in it's pure functional solid form such as `raf().then(cb)`.

Comment: @Redu Ah ok. OP had already used `async`/`await` already though, and `await raf(); draw()` is strictly equivalent to `raf().then(draw);` (and both of them are imperative with side effects, not pure).

Comment: @Bergi OK fair enough. One thing bothers me if naked `requestAnimationFrame(_ => draw())` and promisified `raf().then(draw)` have the same effect? I mean would they both render at the same frame interval?